# Context sensitive help in eclipse cdt / g++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I know how to use CTRL+click or F3 to open declarations of classes in my code for ex, but I would like to have C++ reference help when using Eclipse CDT / g++, something like using F1 on Visual Studio.

I want to get contextual help on C++ keywords, etc

Do you know how to get it ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried it but how about something like this:
-Download gcc/g++ source code. 
-Create a symlink to it from your project.
-Let the indexer complete.